# Array Std object property

Tags: php, arrays, object, properties

I'm trying to get the value from a property but can't seem to make my head around it.

**Output:**

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Name] => layout
        [Count] => 4
    )
[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Name] => node
        [Count] => 2
    )
[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Name] => setting
        [Count] => 5
    )
[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Name] => user
        [Count] => 9
    )
)
```

Any idea in how to get name property? I've tried foreach( $array as $item ) but I don't get the name property value

Comment: `foreach($myArray as $item) { echo $item->Name; }`

Comment: found the problem...can close this.

Comment: When someone answers your question, you should vote up the correct answer(s) and click the checkmark beside the answer you have decided to accept.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
$array = array(... your array ...);
foreach($array as $key) {
    $name = $key->Name;
    prin_r($name);
}
```

This is because you want to access the Name attribute on that object so you use **Object->Attribute**, in this case $key->Name.

Answer (score 0):

`$item` will be referring to each object in your array; you then need to access the object property you want using the accessor 'Name' or 'Count':

```
foreach ($array as $item) {
    echo "Name: " . $item->Name . "\n";
    echo "Count: " . $item->Count . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for accessing a member inside an array of objects : `$array[0]->KEY`

or you can traverse object array

```
$result = array();
foreach ($obj_array as $key => $value) {
    $result[] = $value->Name;
}
print_r($result);
```